# Export the mongodump from one host to another

Tags: mongodb

I am having the mongodump of that collection in host A , Now i need to move that into host B.

I have used,

```
 mongodump --host mongodb1.example.net --port 37017 --username user --password pass /opt/backup/mongodump-2011-10-24
```

but its not worked for me. Any other help on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you us an error message instead if just saying it didn't work?

Comment: it throws error like "ERROR: too many positional options".

Comment: It is the file name doing this, the Linux terminal (or rather PuTTy for me) treats `-` as part of the command even when encapsulated with `"`, you can instead specify a specific out: `./mongodump --host mongodb1.example.net --port 37017 --username user --password pass --out=/opt/backup/mongodump-2011-10-24`
 which works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the terminal, in both native Linux terminal and PuTTY, the `-` within the file name is actually getting treated as a type of option to the command in general. Of course this throws an error when `mongodump` detects the wrong number of options etc which stops it from working. It seems that encapsulation using `'` and `"` does not work either on this front.

An easy and quick fix to this is to manually specify the `--out` option like so:

```
./mongodump --host mongodb1.example.net --port 37017 --username user --password pass --out=/opt/backup/mongodump-2011-10-24
```